# How to avoid raw type mixing generic inheritance and inner classes?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, inner-classes

My class is inheriting from a parent class which uses a generic through a grandparent.
This same class also contains an *Inner Class* - used for a builder.
As I am affecting a variable of the generic type I got a compilation *warning*.

```
Note: Child.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

Here is an over-simplified version of my project.

#### Other.java

```
public class Other
{}
```

#### GrandParent.java

```
public class GrandParent<T>
{
    protected T t;
}
```

#### Parent.java

```
public class Parent<T> extends GrandParent
{}
```

#### Child.java

```
public class Child extends Parent<Other>
{
    // Inner class
    public static class Inner
    {
        public void iDoUnsafeStuff(Other other) {
            Child child = new Child();
            child.t = other;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a more verbose compilation output using `-Xlint:unchecked`.

```
Child.java:8: warning: [unchecked] unchecked assignment to variable t as member of raw type GrandParent
        child.t = other;
```

What is the correct way in Java to use the generic type of a grandparent?

In other words, how to make the `Other` type from `iDoUnsafeStuff()` to match the grandparent generic?

Please note I want to understand what is wrong, not suppress the warning.

Comment: `public class Parent<T> extends GrandParent` - why is that extending raw `GrandParent`?

Comment: What an eyeful question. Clear, short, with an appropriate error description, and an MCVE. I wish all questions were asked so carefully.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Oversimplified I am afraid (see below). But cheers.

Comment: @user2357112 Good question. I think I was looking for the right syntax as I was also having this *is not within bounds* compilation error - see below. Warning vs. error: with a simple warning you feel closer to the solution, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
public class Parent<T> extends GrandParent
```

Change it to

```
public class Parent<T> extends GrandParent<T>
```

in order for `Parent` and `GrandParent` to have the same generic type parameter.

Otherwise there is no relation between the generic type parameter `T` of `Parent` and the `protected T t;` member of `GrandParent`.

Comment: Thank you. It solves the example without solving my problem I am afraid. My mistake as my example was over-simplified. But you pointed me in the right direction. For info, the ```T``` was also extending another class (```public class GrandParent<T extends GenericParent>```) so I got a ```error: type argument T#1 is not within bounds of type-variable T#2```. In case it might help someone, I solved it with the following syntax: ```public class Parent<T extends GenericParent> extends GrandParent<T>```.